# Using an array to store values from a GUI

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I am having a problem with my ControlGUI class. I want to create an array that store integer values of data entered on the GUI JTextfield and return the input for use in a a different class. My code is:

```
public class ControlGUI extends JFrame{

private TemperatureControlAgent myAgent;*emphasized text*

public static JTextField mouldTempField, meltTempField;

public ControlGUI() {

} 
 public static int[] getArray(){

 int input[] = new int [2];
 JTextField t[]=new JTextField [10];
 //public TextFieldArray
 JPanel panel=new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2));
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

{

t[i]= new JTextField(10);
panel.add(t[i]);


 input[0] = Integer.parseInt(mouldTempField.getText());

 input[1] = Integer.parseInt(meltTempField.getText());

 System.out.println("Input mouldTempField"+ input[0]);


  return input;}


ControlGUI (TemperatureControlAgent a)

{
    super (a.getLocalName());

    myAgent = a;



    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout (3, 3));
    p.add(new JLabel ("Mould Temperature Set Value: "));
    mouldTempField = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(mouldTempField);
    p.add(new JLabel ("Melt temperature: "));
    meltTempField = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(meltTempField);
    getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    JButton addButton = new JButton ("Enter");
    addButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

        @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try { 
            String mouldTemp = mouldTempField.getText().trim();
            String meltTemp = meltTempField.getText().trim();

            myAgent.updateCatalogue(Integer.parseInt(mouldTemp), Integer.parseInt(meltTemp));

            mouldTempField.setText("");
            meltTempField.setText("");

        }           
        catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ControlGUI.this, "Invalid values. "+e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }   
    }
    });



    p = new JPanel();
    p.add(addButton);
    getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);




    //Ensure termination of the agent when the user closes the GUI
    //using "close" button
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

        myAgent.doDelete();

        }
    });

    setResizable(false);

 }
public void showGUI(){
    pack ();
    Dimension screenSize;
  screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int CenterX = (int)screenSize.getWidth() / 2;
    int CenterY = (int) screenSize.getHeight() / 2;
    setLocation(CenterX - getWidth() / 2, CenterY - getHeight() / 2 );
    super.setVisible(true);

}



}
```

I am getting a java.lang.NumberFormatException error for line 39 and 40 on the code, that is when I try to extract the integer value of what is inputed on the JTextfield. I am stuck and do not know what to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: What values, exactly, are you entering for `mouldTempField` and `meltTempField`?

Comment: For mouldTempField i entered 45 and for meltTempField i entered 245.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace from your NumberFormatException?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at MouldTemperatureControl.ControlGUI.getArray(ControlGUI.java:39)
 at MouldTemperatureControl.Computation.getAnswer(Computation.java:95)
 at MouldTemperatureControl.TemperatureControlAgent$CoolingOrdersServer.action(TemperatureControlAgent.java:186)
 
 
 at jade.core.Agent.run(Agent.java:1471)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: I can run your code just fine (with tweaking for syntax errors), but I can't replicate your error if I have numbers in both fields.  The only thing I can think of is that your `JTextFields` are both public and static.  Are you *absolutely* sure that nothing else in your program is writing to them and screwing up the numbers you want?

Comment: I do not know what is wrong because it seems like my textfields have nothing in them that can be converted to an integer from my end. Are you able to perform computations by getting the values inputed into these textfields??

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because that one of the `JTextField` has a bot int value, so what you need to do is catch that exception like:

```
 try {
      input[0] = Integer.parseInt(mouldTempField.getText().trim());//use trim to remove white spaces.
 } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      //handle the exception        
 }
```

Comment: I did that. I now have errors on the lower parts of my code such as on line 51, 54 etc etc... Im new to some aspects of Java, how do I fix this??

Comment: What is it that I put in where you have "//handle the exception"

Comment: if you insert something like `51, 54` as one line, that should not work because it works with a single number, seconds handle the exception, means the code necessary in case the input wasn't a numeric, maybe a you want to log that, or appear a error msg, that depends on your logic.

Comment: Ok. Let me try that. Thank you

Comment: System.out.println("You've entered non-integer number");
                System.out.println("This caused " + e);                                                                    That is how I handled my exception and the code gives me the error print line but my error doesnt values I want. How do I fix this? I need to use the array values input[0] and input[1] in a computation on another method but this is impossible now because the array isgivng me those values as zeros

Answer (score 0):

`actionPerformed()` is calling a method on your agent and then clearing the text fields like this:

```
String mouldTemp = mouldTempField.getText().trim();
String meltTemp = meltTempField.getText().trim();
myAgent.updateCatalogue(Integer.parseInt(mouldTemp), Integer.parseInt(meltTemp));
mouldTempField.setText(""); // no more data!
meltTempField.setText(""); // no more data!
```

From your stack trace, it looks like `TemperatureControlAgent.updateCatalogue()` kicks off some analysis in a separate thread. This new thread then comes back later and runs `ControlGUI.getArray()` as a static method, which tries to read the data again:

```
input[0] = Integer.parseInt(mouldTempField.getText());
input[1] = Integer.parseInt(meltTempField.getText());
```

But since back in your GUI thread, you've already blown away your data, you are now trying to parse an empty string, causing the NFE.

Comment: Ok.So does this mean that I shouldnt clean up the date using the:     meltTempField.setText("");  Instead I should leave my values that way??

Comment: Well, you could move the cleanup to the end of `getArray()`, or keep the cleanup where it is, but pass the values to `getArray()` from the agent, since it's already got them from when you invoked `updateCatalogue`.  I'm not really sure what `getArray()` is supposed to be doing, but this is why you don't normally make your data and methods static.  It tends to cause these kinds of side-effects.

Comment: I used your 1st suggestion. I will leave it at that for now and progress to the next stages of my project. I think it is OK if my values are retained in the ControlGUI. Thank you